# How to resolve promise in Next.js within a foreach?

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I'm having trouble getting the foreach data to resolve before passing it to DrawChart();
When I pass it to DrawChart() the applicationName is always undefined.

How would I make it so that its not undefined?

```
useEffect(() => {
if (!effectRan.current) {
    let sentiments: any;
    sentiments = calculateSentiments();

    sentiments.forEach(async (sentiment: any) => {
      sentiment.applicationName = await getProductNameById(sentiment.applicationId);
    });

    DrawChart(sentiments);
  
}
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

`forEach` will not wait for the previous async operation to finish. If you need to get the data in order, consider using `map` combined with `Promise.all` instead.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (!effectRan.current) {
    const fetchProductNamesAndDrawChart = async () => {
      let sentiments = calculateSentiments();
  
      const updatedSentiments = await Promise.all(
        sentiments.map(async (sentiment) => {
          const productName = await getProductNameById(sentiment.applicationId);
          return {
            ...sentiment,
            applicationName: productName
          };
        })
      );
  
      DrawChart(updatedSentiments);
    };
  
    fetchProductNamesAndDrawChart();
  }
  
  // Add dependencies if any exist
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `async/await` inside of `forEach`. The `forEach` method doesn't wait for the promises to resolve because it's not designed to work with async callback functions.

You could instead create an array of `promises` and then use `Promise.all` to wait for all of the promises to resolve. Like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (!effectRan.current) {
    const sentiments = calculateSentiments();

    const promises = sentiments.map(async (sentiment: any) => {
      sentiment.applicationName = await getProductNameById(sentiment.applicationId);
      return sentiment;
    });

    Promise.all(promises).then((updatedSentiments) => {
      DrawChart(updatedSentiments);
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.error("Failed to fetch product names:", error);
    });
  }
}, []);
```